# ActiveAdmin with Paranoia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, acts-as-paranoid

I want to soft delete(archive) records through the index view but the default action actually destroys the record completely rather than adding a timestamp deleted_at column.

Ive tried to override the link_to method to be sure that activeadmin isnt doing anything to the link but it had no effect on the outcome

```
link_to "Archive", admin_events_path(resource), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?", class: "member_link delete_link"
```

Comment: did you add `acts_as_paranoid` in your model and restart server after installing gem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that minglin with active_admin was a bit though when we want to change how it internally does work. But there is a gem -> `active_admin_paranoia` that does exactly what you need. Now all you have to do is set up paranoia gem properly and include `act_as_paranoid` in your model declaration.

link to the gem: https://github.com/raihan2006i/active_admin_paranoia